# DoCmd.OpenReport work well in some pcs and do not work (freeze access) in other pcs

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem with my access program and I would be very glad if someone could help me!

We have an application in Microsoft Access developed. It worked without errors in my PC (ex.: **PC A**). However, running the same application in another computer (ex.: **PC B**). The application works perfectly in **PC B** with the exception of this command **DoCmd.OpenReport**.

When I run this command in the **PC B** the application freeze. It stops and I have to force closed it. The big problem is that we do not have any errors report from Access or Windows. Even if we debug the application, it freezes without returning any feedback. 
We also checked in the **window 10** the event viewer application to check if there are any errors. However, we also did not get any feedback.

What we also have tried:
1) reinstall the **office 2010**
2) checked also the dependencies libraries on both pcs (**PC-A and PC-B**). They are identical. 
3) checked both hardware and windows versions. They are also the same.

This is a part of the code where it freezes only in PC B:

```
strSQL = "((mid(Tb_History.strFormName,1,4)=" & "'" & Mid(strFormName_IN, 1, 4) & "'" & ") " "AND (Tb_History.strDataPrimaryKey=" & "'" & strKey_IN & "'" & "))"

 DoCmd.OpenReport "History_Show", acViewPreview, , strSQL
```

Can someone, please, help me?
Thanks!

Cheers,
Marcelo

Comment: Have you considered a printer issue? Print preview needs to pull in printer information for the printer the report is going to print on. If there's a bad default printer that can cause Access to hang.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  Erik !However, the both computers have the same printer installed.

Comment: Hello everybody, I found the solution and I would like to post here. Maybe it can help someone. It was a bug in the report access object. I deleted this object and create another one with the same fields and linked data as the first one. It worked perfect now in any computer!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and I would like to post here. Maybe it can help someone. It was a bug in the report access object. I deleted this object and create another one with the same fields and linked data as the first one. It worked perfect now in any computer!!! –